# Infopath's built in Username() function returning "i:0#.w|Domain\UserName" instead of just UserName?

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-enterprise

How can I modify the UserName() return string to display only the username as opposed to 
 "i:0#.w|Domain\UserName"?

When I had the same form in my development environment it returned Domain\UserName and none of the prefix characters (i:0#.w|). Once I moved it to the production though I get this now:
  i:0#.w|Domain\UserName

I am open to using other alternatives as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a substring after "\" for the user name, or after "|" for the domain and user name.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/functions-in-infopath-HP001155281.aspx

Answer (score 7):

The reason you're seeing this is that your production farm uses Claims AuthN whereas your dev enviroment the classic mode. You should probably make your code handle both scenarios.

Here are some details about the claims encoding: http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-Claims-encoding-works-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx

Comment: @rjcup3 I am simply using UserName() builtin function in infopath to retrieve the username. How would I implement this using Xpath

Comment: You have the following XPath string functions to use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256180(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks guys! Got what I was looking for. I used         substring-after(username(),"\")

Comment: Wictor is right in saying you should handle this issue for both scenarios. Wish I would have seen your comment earlier but it wasn't on my answer so it didn't get flagged, sorry.

Comment: Assuming all usernames have a back slash could potentially break your solution, if you start adding federated accounts for instance

Answer (score 6):

While researching this myself, I found a solution that might be a bit better than a substring.  You might want to try the following:

```
SPClaimProviderManager manager = SPClaimProviderManager.Local;

if (manager != null)
{
    if (SPClaimProviderManager.IsEncodedClaim(encodedString))
        username = manager.DecodeClaim(encodedString).Value;
    else
        username = encodedString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to parse the username from the returned string as explained by RJ above. But you might want to show the Display name instead of user name. you will need to query the user profile service from infopath to extract the Display Name for that username().

Answer (score -2):

This is an alternative solution: 
http://zimmergren.net/technical/tip-getting-the-normal-domain-username-from-the-claims-username-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers! Instead add details to your answer from the link you reference so that the link is mearly a source to the complete information