# How to promote person DisplayName in InfoPath and get the correct value in SharePoint?

Tags: infopath

How do I do property promotion on a Person field in InfoPath to get the correct value displayed in SharePoint table? When I did property promotion on DisplayName field under person, it returned me values that look like:

> i:0#.f|membership|john_doe

When I'm looking to see something like

> John Doe

I am using sharepoint 2010 with infopath 2010.
The promoted field comes up as a Single Line of Text instead of Person

Comment: Hopefully this helps answer your question:

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36240/infopaths-built-in-username-function-returning-i0-wdomain-username-inste

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, when InfoPath promotes a People Picker to SharePoint, it comes across as a single line of text as you stated.  To get the Display Name, make sure you are promoting the `pc:Person/DisplayName` property.  You will need to apply a function such as `first`.  `pc:Person/AccountId` will show the account name of who logs into SharePoint (`DOMAIN\Account` if using Windows authentication).

If you want to use presence or a Person column in SharePoint, you can have InfoPath promote the `pc:Person/AccountId` and then set up a workflow to copy over the account name into a Person column.  It requires an extra step, but it works well.

[Here's a good article](http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=178) that will help you deal with InfoPath people pickers effectively.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What is your Person field's 'Show Field' setting set to within the SharePoint list? If it's set to Name (With Presence), you'll get the value you're seeing. Set the 'Show Field' setting to just 'Name' to see if that helps.

Comment: It doesn't come as Person field, it comes a Single Line of Text field from infopath